# Rails 4.1 enum raises error instead set object as invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord, enums

I am using the Rails 4.1 enum field

```
class User
    enum category: [ :client, :seller, :provider ]
end
```

When the user signs up, he chooses from a select box his category. The default is empty, because I want to force the user to choose one option.

If the user does not select any option, I would like to return to the form with a validation message. Here is the select box code in sign up form

```
    <%= f.select :category, [], {}, class: "form-control" do  %>
        <option value="99">Choose an option</option>

        <% User.categories.each do |cat,code| %>
            <option value="<%= code %>" <% if params["user"] && code.to_s == params["user"]["category"] %>selected='selected'<%end%> ><%= t(cat) %></option>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

When the controller creates the user, instead of adding a validation error to the record, it raises an exception. How to avoid this?

```
ArgumentError - '99' is not a valid category:
  (gem) activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/enum.rb:103:in `block (3 levels) in enum'
  (gem) activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
  (gem) activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes
```

Answer (score 4):

I really dislike the reasoning as stated in the issue listed above. Since the value is coming over the wire, it should be treated the same as a freetext input where the expectation is to validate in the model and not the controller. This is especially true in APIs where the developers have even less of a say as far as expected input coming from form data (for example).

In case anyone wants a hack, here is what I came up with. Passes basic testing, but would love feedback if anyone finds issues with it:

```
class User
  enum category: [ :client, :seller, :provider ]

  def category=(val)
    super val
  rescue
    @__bad_cat_val = val
    super nil
  end
end
```

This will reset category to `nil` and we can then validate the field:

```
class User
...
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

The problem is that we *really* want to be validating `inclusion`, not just `presence`. To get around that we have to capture the input (e.g. as above in `def category=`). Then we can output our message using that value:

```
class User
...
  validates :category, inclusion: { 
    in: categories.keys, 
    message: ->(record,error) {
      val = record.instance_variable_get(:@__bad_cat_val)
      return "Category is required" if val.nil?
      "#{val.inspect} is not a valid category"
    }
  }
end
```

That will give us messages for presence and inclusion. If you need to fine tune it more you would have to use a custom validator (I believe).

Comment: Here's another workaround option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416806/47185 (extracted as a concern so it's more reusable)

Answer (score 1):

The `enum` in `Rails` always raise a error if you try to set an invalid value. There is no such validation and add an error message to `base` or adding a validation error to the record. You should create own validation by `rescue` errors.

```
=> u = User.last
=> User.genders
=> {"male"=>0, "female"=>1}
=> u.gender = 'boy'
#> ArgumentError: 'boy' is not a valid gender
=> u.gender = 'male'
#> "male"
```

Comment: I don't know how to catch this error. In my Model file. I tried to create my own validation. def industry_must_be_valid
    if(self.industry != nil)
      begin
        if(User.industries[self.industry] != nil)
          return true
        else
          errors.add(:industry, "is not valid")
          return false
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        errors.add(:industry, "is not valid")
        return false
      end
    end

Answer (score 1):

Read: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971

Specifically read [Senny](https://github.com/senny)'s comment:

> The current focus of AR enums is to map a set of states (labels) to an integer for performance reasons. Currently assigning a wrong state is considered an application level error and not a user input error. That's why you get an ArgumentError.

That being said you can always set nil or an empty string to the enum attribute without raising an error:

```
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
```

and add a simple presence validation like:

```
validates :category, presence: { message: "is required" }
```

Comment: What if an entry like  "Orange" is submitted, which is not part of the enum values. An exception will be thrown. In your validates function within the model, how would you check for this?

Comment: In that case I think the best approach is to validate **:category** params in the controller, and  check if the received value is within the enum values. If it isn't we can just default to nil and let the model validation take care.

Answer (score -2):

In case someone still struggles with this. You can add a standard [inclusion](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) validation like this (in the User model):

```
validates :category, inclusion: { 
            in: categories.keys, 
            message: "%{value} is not a valid category"
          }
```

Comment: @developer033 yep, this example does not work. this one -› https://github.com/CristiRazvi/enum_attributes_validation although being a gem, does work